# For n = 2 ... 11 set up Vandermonde matrix A of size m × n and for each n given data set a. Matlab

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matlab

I am given set of 50 data points with values {a^(i),b^(i)} for i=1,...,50
stored in the arrays a and b.
I know that the Vandermonde matrix A has size m x n, where n = 2 ... 11 and m is the size of the array a.

I want to to fit the data with a polynomial of degree (n − 1), for n = 2,...,11. To do that for each n I have to set up the Vandermonde matrix A of size m × n.

The Vandermonde matrix A solves the following equation: 
`A^T*A*x = A^T*b`

Where the A^T is the transpose matrix and I have b already given. 
Also we know that `Aij = (a^(i))^(j−1)` for j = 1,...,n,
What confuses me is how to set the matrix for n = 2,..,11.

What my line of thought is:
I have `m = length(a);` this will set up m = 50;

n = 11;

Then `A=ones(m,n);` This creates a matrix A filled with ones that has the correct size.

However I am not sure how to populate the matrix. 
I wrote the following for loop which I thought will populate the matrix:

```
for n = 2:11
    j=n;
    for i = 1:50
        A(i,n) = (a^(i))^(j-1);
    end
end
```

Could you help me please with setting up the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid for-loops if you can in matlab.
A **hint** is you can use

```
meshgrid(1:k,1:n)
```

for example

```
[rows,cols] = meshgrid(1:3,1:4)
```

returns 
    $$rows = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&3\\1&2&3\\1&2&3\\1&2&3\end{array}\right], cols= \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\\2&2&2\\3&3&3\\4&4&4\end{array}\right]$$

Then you can use point operators on matrices.

```
a.*b
```

calculates elementwise multiplication

```
a.^b
```

calculates elementwise power

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the help! I am not familiar with the meshgrid function and I have not studied it, so I am not sure if I am allowed to use it. However I tweaked my code and I dropped one of the for loops:
`%Load the data points: 
load('data_points_50.mat');
% Create the Vandermonde matrix 
m = length(a);
n = 11;
A=[];
for j=1:n
  A = [A,a.^j];
end`

This generates a matrix that is the correct size, however, I am not sure how to verify if it is the correct matrix.